# Enabling timestamp in NodeJS (loopback) Logs

Tags: node.js, docker, logging, loopbackjs

I have a nodeJS loopback application running in a Docker Container.

When I monitor the logs there is no timestamp for the logs, resulting in obvious challenges.

Is there a way to enable timestamps for these logs?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to add the -t option.

So..

```
docker service logs -ft {NAME_OF_THE_SERVICE}
```

Will output the logs with the tstamp included in the output

Answer (score 0):

As you did not share your Dockerfile or and configuration of logging in loopback I create a simple app using loopback-cli and tested it. Everything working fine.

create hello work as i worked on express not worked on loopback but follow this article

http://loopback.io/getting-started/

Here is my docker file

```
FROM goabode/nodejs

VOLUME [ "/opt/nodejs" ]
COPY . /opt/nodejs

WORKDIR /opt/nodejs
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node" , "." ]
```

I add winston in `server/boot/root.js` for testing

```
   'use strict';

module.exports = function(server) {
  var winston = require('winston');
  // Install a `/` route that returns server status
  var router = server.loopback.Router();
  router.get('/', server.loopback.status());
  router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    winston.log('info', 'This is a log event', {timestamp: Date.now(), pid: process.pid});
    winston.info('This is another log event', {timestamp: Date.now(), pid: process.pid});
    res.send('pong');
  });
  server.use(router);
};
```

Follow this article

https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

[image]

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Using+logging+libraries